# CSS display inline two form without using float

Tags: html, css

in `html/css` i have simply two form and i want to set that to single row as `inline` widthout using `float`. you can see this [ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vw64zn2w/)

in this below code i want to set `display:inline` to have single row as two `div`. like with this screen shot:

[image]
HTML:

```
<div class='single-page'>
    <div id="verification-panel">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>verification code</legend>
                <label>Mobile Number:</label>
                <input type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="EX:">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
                <button type="button" class="btn">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="activation-panel">
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Active Acount</legend>
                <label>Verfication code:</label>
                <input type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="Verficcation code">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
                <button type="button" class="btn">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display:inline-block;`

```
#verification-panel,#activation-panel{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: yeah, but the attribute class='single-page' should be in element verification-panel and activation-panel. Or you can simple add attribute style='display:inline-block' on those divs

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code to your CSS section:

```
.single-page {
display: inline-block;
width: 769px;
}

.verification-panel,
.activation-panel { display: inline-block; }
```

To get the forms inline, apart from declaring the `display: inline-block` to both classes, you have to define a width for the parent container big enough to let them sit besides each other.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vw64zn2w/3/)

```
   .single-page{
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
}
#verification-panel,#activation-panel{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49%; // because of margin or etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#verification-panel,#activation-panel{
display:inline-block; width:250px;
```

}